# UnicodeEncodeError while accessing db in django admin

Tags: python, django, unicode, encoding, python-unicode

When trying to access data base via admin I get this error

> UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/nota_app/demographic/

```
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x8e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is what my model is:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Demographic(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    region = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ...
```

And I am saving the objects in this manner:

```
new_demographic = Demographic(
            status = smart_unicode(my_dict[i]['status']),
            region = smart_unicode(my_dict[i]['network']),
            ...
        )            
        new_demographic.save()
```

I have also tried using `unicode()` and `encode('utf-8')` methods but sadly, they had no effect as well. Can anyone please help me with a workaround for this?

This is the full traceback:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/nota_app/demographic/
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x8e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/nota_app/demographic/
Django Version: 1.7.9
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x8e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: C:\Users\KESHAV\Desktop\StackQueue\nota\nota_app\models.py in __str__, line 87
Python Executable:  C:\Users\KESHAV\Desktop\StackQueue\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue\\nota',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue',
 'C:\\Users\\KESHAV\\Desktop\\StackQueue\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 6 Jan 2016 16:28:48 +0000
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Made edit, please have a look.

Comment: The traceback tells you that the error is occurring on line 87, in your `__str__` method. Is that the `__str__` method for the `Demographic` model? What does it look like?

Comment: It simply returns the information from the object, this is the line 
`return str(self.region+", "+self.country)`

Comment: I now changed the code to `return str(self.region.encode("utf-8")+", "+self.country.encode("utf-8"))` and now the traceback shows error at `C:\Users\KESHAV\Desktop\StackQueue\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py in <lambda>, line 38`

Comment: The problem is in the `__str__` method, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `@python_2_unicode_compatible`, then your `__str__` method should return a unicode string.

You havee `str(self.region+", "+self.country)`, which tries to convert the unicode string to a byte string in Python 2. To fix the problem, change the method to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.region + u"," + self.country
```

Comment: I made a slight change to your suggestion and used something like this:
`return smart_unicode(self.region+", "+self.country)`... It works like a charm now! Thanks! :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `smart_unicode`, because the model fields `self.region` and `self.country` should already be unicode strings. I don't think that using `smart_unicode` will cause any problems, but it does look a bit unusual.